# Timed out retrying: cy.type() failed because this element is not visible. has CSS property: position: fixed and it's being covered by another element:

Tags: vue.js, cypress

Unable to find the textbox element in a new pop-up window.

Actual Result:

[image: Throws exception]

Expected Result:
Able to type value in the text box.

Adding the cypress snippet below,

```
 it("Add business test",function(){         
   cy.xpath("//a[contains(.,'1099/W-2')]").click({force:true});
   cy.wait(5000); 
   cy.get(':nth-child(2) > .btn-hover-shrink > .v-btn__content').click({force: true});
   cy.contains('Start Now').click({force:true});
   //Add business pop-up open
   cy.contains('Business Name').click({force: true}).type("Test LLC");
})
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add `{force: true}` with `type()` to disable error checking -

```
cy.get('[id*="input-"]').type("Test LLC", {force: true});
```

Comment: I used the same code- `cy.contains('Business Name').click({force: true}).type("Test LLC", {force: true});` It throws exception -  **cy.type() failed because it requires a valid typeable element.**.And i change the code - `cy.get('#input-186').type('Test LLC', { force: true });`. It works, value is geeting type.But the id value ig getting changed frequently.

Comment: You can change the locator to something like this `cy.get('[id*="input-"]')`.

Comment: But all the text box has the id = input-<number>

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that you are trying to `type()` into the label. That's because `cy.contains('sometext')` selects the element "owning" the text, which is the label, but you can also select a parent by using the pattern `cy.contains(<parentSelector>, 'sometext')`

Take a look at the page DOM, if you have a common parent of the `<label>` and the  `<textarea>` (or `<input>`), like this

```html
<div>
  <label>Business Name</label>
  <input />
</div>
```

you can target that parent in the `.contains()`

```js
cy.contains('div', 'Business Name')
  .find('input')           // drill down to the element receiving the text
  .should('be.visible')    // since there's a toolbar in the mix, wait for visibility
  .type('Test LLC')
```

An alternative might be to use [.closest()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/closest)

```js
cy.contains('Business Name')  // gives you the label
  .closest('input')           // nearby element receiving the text
  .should('be.visible')       // wait for visibility
  .type('Test LLC')
```

---

Here's one more way, making use of the label's "for" attribute

```js
cy.contains('Business Name')  // gives you the label
  .invoke('attr', 'for')      // which id is it for?
  .then(id => {
    cy.get('#' + id)          // get the actionable element
      .should('be.visible')   // wait for visibility
      .type('Test LLC')
  })
```

Comment: Thanks. Third solution using "for" attribute we are able to type the value and we have given {force: true} in the type.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the Vuetify form component [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/forms/#usage) which has a similar HTML to yours

```html
<div class="v-text-field__slot">
  <label for="input-6" class="v-label theme--light" style="left: 0px; right: auto; position: absolute;">Last name</label>
  <input required="required" id="input-6" type="text">
</div>
```

the same test code you have succeeds on the sample code

```
cy.contains('Last name')  
  .click({force: true})
  .type("Test LLC");        // text appears in the input
```

but if I simulate the covering toolbar, it fails with the same error you have.

---

Adding `.type("Test LLC", {force: true})` also fails with a different error

```
cy.contains('Last name')  
  .click({force: true})
  .type("Test LLC", {force: true});
```

> cy.type() failed because it requires a valid typeable element.

---

Using the parent contains to find the "typeable element" and applying `force: true` option works

```
cy.contains('div', 'Business Name')
  .find('input')          
  .should('be.visible')
  .type("Test LLC", {force: true})
```

This assumes the toolbar remains static and does not animate away, in which case it would work without the `force: true` option.